# Group and sum data that is generate by nested loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sum, grouping

I'd generated an array in PHP through below code. An investor array is taken, multiple investors multiple emi tenure data are pushed. Now I want to build an array emi tenure wise (like result sample).

```
$investors = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++){

    //emi-data push start
    $emiTenures = array();
    for($k = 0; $k < 3 ; $k++){
    
        $data =[
            'b_amount' => 1*$k+$i,
            'recv_total' => 1+$k+$i
        ]; 
        array_push($emiTenures,$data);   
    }
    //emi-data push end
    
    array_push($investors,$emiTenures);    
}
print_r($investors);
```

output of above array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [b_amount] => 0
                    [recv_total] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [b_amount] => 1
                    [recv_total] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [b_amount] => 2
                    [recv_total] => 3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [b_amount] => 1
                    [recv_total] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [b_amount] => 2
                    [recv_total] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [b_amount] => 3
                    [recv_total] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

**result sample : I want to get result array like below : (emiTenures wise)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [b_amount] => 1 // $investors[0][0]['b_amount'] + $investors[1][0]['b_amount']
            [recv_total] => 3 // $investors[0][0]['recv_total'] + $investors[1][0]['recv_total']
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [b_amount] => 3 // $investors[0][1]['b_amount'] + $investors[1][1]['b_amount']
            [recv_total] => 5 // $investors[0][1]['recv_total'] + $investors[1][1]['recv_total']
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [b_amount] => 5
            [recv_total] => 7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the `$k` values on the first level and sum the values that belong in each group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rSStU))

```
$investors = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < 3; ++$k) {
        $investors[$k]['b_amount'] = ($investors[$k]['b_amount'] ?? 0) + 1 * $k + $i;
        $investors[$k]['recv_total'] = ($investors[$k]['recv_total'] ?? 0) + 1 + $k + $i;
    }
}
var_export($investors);
```

Comment: $investors[$k]['b_amount'] = ($investors[$k]['b_amount'] ?? 0) + $generatedArray[$i][$k]['b_amount'];

$investors[$k]['recv_total'] = ($investors[$k]['recv_total'] ?? 0) + $generatedArray[$i][$k]['recv_total'];